# Recover draft text message

Tags: sms

I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 Star.

I was recently hospitalized and needed to write important information but didn't have anything to write on. I chose a random contact and started to write the information as a text message and never sent it because it was not for that person.

When I left the window, a message appeared "message saved as draft"; later I chose the same contact to add an important link and it appeared in the window but the previous draft messages disappeared.

I need to recover that important information and cannot find any folder where my draft was supposed to be saved.

Comment: Good messengers like signal allow to send you messages to yourself ("note to self").

Comment: even if data is still there (you don't know) you can't recover because of lacking permissions. better use any notes or calendar [app](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client) in future

Comment: settings app has notification history widget for viewing recent incoming notifications, but i doubt you will find a draft message there. dialer app has conversation history including deleted messages, but again no drafts here

Comment: Please clarify if you're using Samsung's own Messaging app or other texting apps. Though, some apps don't support multiple drafts, so previous drafts will be gone if a user chooses to create a new text message. It's preferable to download and install a note-keeping app for this purpose. Otherwise, and in the worst case, use the Contacts app for adding notes on certain contacts instead of relying on Messaging app's drafts.